# Angular 13 - What replaces DeployURL

Tags: angular-cli

I've just upgraded a project to angular 13, and it removed my "deployUrl" option under serve. What's replacing this ?

For context my prod deployments are under a path (/appname/) so I have that in the deployUrl for build, but that's a bit annoying when using ng serve during development so I was using a different deployUrl (just /) in serve.

Without it I have to use localhost:4200/appname/ when using ng serve, which isn't the end of the world but a bit annoying.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end my solution was to replace my deployUrl with a servePath in angular.json :

```json
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "console:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "console:build:dev",
              "servePath": "/"
            }
```

Then I added what used to be my deploy url as a proxied path in proxy.conf.json :

```json
{
    "/mypath/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:4200/",
      "pathRewrite": {"^/mypath" : ""}
    }
  }
```

With this I got back the same behavior when using serve : my prod is still deployed under /mypath, but my local serve instance still works directly on /.
I'll have to figure something for build before they remove deployUrl there, but baseHref might do, I need to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

From [Angular official docs](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angular-devkitbuild-angular), it doesn't sound like `deployURL` was removed in v13 but it may be removed in v15:

> Use `baseHref` option, `APP_BASE_HREF` DI token or a combination of both instead. For more information, see the [deploy url](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url).

Comment: It wasn't removed from the build options, but it was removed from the serve options, for some reason they seem to be separate.

Comment: I did find a solution last week though, I'm now using `servePath: "/"` in the serve options, and I proxy my previous deployUrl to / with a rewrite using proxy.conf.json, works like a charm. That won't work for build of course so I'll have to figure out a better solution before v15, I'll look into baseHref but I remember trying it and it doesn't work quite the same I think

Comment: @Kevin Do you mind posting your comment as an answer? Sounds like you found the answer to your question, that's awesome!

Comment: sure done, thanks